# Where can I ask a question about estimating project costs?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm interested in asking this question:

> I have a client whom have "idea" of his project "that is in his mind". He said he is not going to share any details, knowledge, and ideas until we have a contract because as he's saying "he's worried about someone stealing his ideas". However, in our first meeting on client side, I think I get global global overview what he wants to have (generally). Now he's awaiting my offer and that's where I stack on to prepare it to him including price.
>
> Should I just prepare an offer on the knowledge i have? For instance I know he want application to create article/edit it, associate with some elements blabla... However we haven't talked about details, how this information should be inserted by users etc.
>
> Should I propose just my view generally and prepare an offer with price how i see this and how this could be done giving general information on an offer and final price? However what about details, should them be on this offer or just general list and later on we should talk about this? I am bit confused.. Please of your advice.

Is there a site on the Stack Exchange network that will accept a question like this?

Comment: Welcome! The question's definitely off topic here but we welcome questions about where on the network a question would be on topic. Please consider fleshing out your question to explain what you're looking for more specifically (assuming my title change isn't accurate).

Comment: Yes that's correct let me know what is right place to raise that question

Comment: @JimmyJimm included two options you got

Answer (score 1):

Two possible places I can think that you may consider for targets of your question are:

1. [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/): *"Q&A for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting"*.

   I am a regular user of this site, and of what I can tell your proposed Q could fit there. Still, please read the tour and help section (and look around a bit) so you can rephrase your question to better fit there

   I believe you could focus on "*Should I just prepare an offer on the knowledge i have?*". However, "should I" question are not taken positively over there (as they are asking for answerers to make a choice for you), so try to rephrase it to something like *"What can I do to give an acceptable estimate with the information I have?"*, or *"How can I prepare an adequate estimate with the information I have?"*, etc.
2. [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/): *"Q&A for project managers"*

   This is a Beta site I found searching, and although I am not an user of it, its topic seems to suggest that you can try and post your question there. Again, I suggest you read the help section of that site (and perhaps double-check on their chat) before posting.